# Memcached consistent hashing - spymemcached

Tags: memcached, spymemcached, consistent-hashing

I want to have memcached consistant hashing enabled. I've looked at phpinfo(); and I can see the following - last line "memcached.sess_consistent_hash":

```
memcached

memcached support   enabled
Version 2.1.0
libmemcached version    1.0.4
Session support yes
igbinary support    no
json support    no

Directive   Local Value Master Value
memcached.sess_consistent_hash  0   0
```

Should this be set to one to enable consistant hashing or am I going in the wrong direction with this? I'm using spymemcached. Is there a different way to do this?

thankyou

** Also how do I enable this - I can't find an entry in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

SpyMemcached is a Java library, so I'm not sure how you're integrating with PHP, but you can turn on cosistent hashing in SpyMemcached like so:

```
ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
        .setLocatorType(Locator.CONSISTENT).build();
MemcachedClient client = 
        new MemcachedClient(connFactory, AddrUtil.getAddresses(serverString));
```

Comment: If I do this from different app servers, all spy clients must have the same config and server address list, correct? I have 5 mc servers, so I just list them in `serverString`?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. I would ensure that all your app servers are configured identically to ensure that they're getting and setting objects to the same MC nodes.